# Implementing forgot password feature, Search and if email exists, send email Node.JS does not work as Expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

i want to do something like when a user searches a mongoDB Database, and user exists it should then send an email to the user with a password Reset link. For some reason it does not work as expected.
it just goes ahead to send emails, And does not check if the email exists , i dont know why it behaves so.

My code looks like this :

```
exports.forgot_pass = function(req,res,next){

    User.findOne({
        user_email : req.body.user_email
    }).exec((err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message : err});
            return;
        }
        if(!user){
            res.status(400).send({message: "Sorry Email does not Exist!"});
        }else{
            var user_email = req.body.user_email;
            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service:'gmail',
                host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                port:'587',
                auth:{
                    user: '**************@gmail.com',
                    pass: '***********'
                },
                secureConnection: 'false',
                tls: {
                    ciphers: 'SSLv3',
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                }
            });
            const mailOptions = {
                from :'***********@gmail.com',
                to: user_email,
                subject: 'Please Reset your Password',
                html : '<h3>Dear User</h3><p>You have requested to Reset your password. To Reset your password Successfully, Follow the Link bellow to Reset it</p><p>Click <a href="https://**********/user/resetPassword.jsp">https://onepercentsoft.oxygen.com/user/resetPassword.jsp</a></p><p>This Email is subject to mandatory instruction.</p><p>Regards,</p><p>Online Service</p>'
            };
        
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
                if(error)throw error;
                return res.send({error:false, data: info, message: 'OK'});
            })
        }
    });

};
```

But this does not check for anything, It just goes ahead and sends the email. I need help here.

Comment: If you're using a callback, it needs to be passed to `findOne`, not `exec`. Please refer to mongoose [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `async await`. The problem may be related on how you are handling promises.

```
exports.forgot_pass = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const { user_email } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ user_email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Sorry Email does not Exist!' });
    }
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: '587',
      auth: {
        user: '**************@gmail.com',
        pass: '***********',
      },
      secureConnection: 'false',
      tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    });
    const mailOptions = {
      from: '***********@gmail.com',
      to: user_email,
      subject: 'Please Reset your Password',
      html: '<h3>Dear User</h3><p>You have requested to Reset your password. To Reset your password Successfully, Follow the Link bellow to Reset it</p><p>Click <a href="https://**********/user/resetPassword.jsp">https://onepercentsoft.oxygen.com/user/resetPassword.jsp</a></p><p>This Email is subject to mandatory instruction.</p><p>Regards,</p><p>Online Service</p>',
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) throw error;
      return res.send({ error: false, data: info, message: 'OK' });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: Earlier i did not use async function, basically what i did worked, likewise what you did. Works fine as well.
Once again, Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Sending email will take a little bit time. first of all you have to check is email exist. if exist then you have to send mail. for this purpose make your function asynchronous and us e await.

```
exports.forgot_pass = async function(req,res,next){

    await User.findOne({
        user_email : req.body.user_email
    }).exec((err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message : err});
            return;
        }
        if(!user){
            res.status(400).send({message: "Sorry Email does not Exist!"});
        }else{
            var user_email = req.body.user_email;
            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service:'gmail',
                host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                port:'587',
                auth:{
                    user: '**************@gmail.com',
                    pass: '***********'
                },
                secureConnection: 'false',
                tls: {
                    ciphers: 'SSLv3',
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                }
            });
            const mailOptions = {
                from :'***********@gmail.com',
                to: user_email,
                subject: 'Please Reset your Password',
                html : '<h3>Dear User</h3><p>You have requested to Reset your password. To Reset your password Successfully, Follow the Link bellow to Reset it</p><p>Click <a href="https://**********/user/resetPassword.jsp">https://onepercentsoft.oxygen.com/user/resetPassword.jsp</a></p><p>This Email is subject to mandatory instruction.</p><p>Regards,</p><p>Online Service</p>'
            };
        
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
                if(error)throw error;
                return res.send({error:false, data: info, message: 'OK'});
            })
        }
    });

};
```